# Pycharm - backspace is not working as expected in HTML file

Tags: pycharm

I am using Pycharm CE 2018.1.4. Backspace is working as expected in `.py` file. However, if I edit a `.html` file, and use template syntax like `{%endblock}`, it does not remove space before `{%endblock}`. If I click backspace, it goes to previous line. Please check the picture. I cannot remove the space  before `{%endblock}` in line `10`.[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

I am using licensed pycharm student version. The below settings should help you in getting the behaviour you want.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can hold down the **Shift** key and **Left Arrow key** simultaneously to select space before ‍`{%endblock}`, then press the **Backspace** button.

[image]